# Environment of another user in a child process

Tags: login, environment-variables

I have a parent process running as 'root' user. After `fork()`, `execl()` and `setuid()/setgid()`, the child process is started as another OS user (say user1).

Printing the environment shows that this is same as the root environment (as if logging in as root) and not as if logging in as user1. Why?

Is there a way to read the environment of user1 in the child process?

Comment: You want running environment or just environment ?

Answer (score 3):

Each process has [its own environment, copied from the parent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/exception-of-inheritance-of-environment-variables). If the parent is a shell, there's a concept of *exportable variables* which needs to be considered, but this does not apply when you are dealing with `exec()` etc directly. The `LOGNAME` variable is typically set by a login shell, you're just seeing a leftover value that was not reset. So, you *are* seeing the child environment. On some systems you cannot easily access the parent (or other process) environment, on Linux you can do this easily (subject to permissions) [via `/proc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process))

You can probably reproduce the effect you are seeing by trying both `su` and `su -`, the latter will initialize a shell login environment which will (almost certainly) reset `LOGNAME` amongst other things, the former will leave it untouched.

Using the `env` command is one way of getting a clean environment when starting a new process from a command line, you should check the `execle()` documentation on your system to see how to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check user env using :

```
su -l user_name  -c "run_programm && env"
```

Or you can check `env` of child process by using it's pid ,

suppose your child process pid is `24112` , then just check `env` using :

```
cat /proc/24112/environ
```

Comment: I needed programatically (Unix/C) and common for all the Unix platforms.

Comment: @BaluT, you can use `execl("su", "-l", "user_name", "-c", "program");` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Some bits of information:

- You can use `execle` or `execve` to provide enviroment variables to the child. You can use this both to suppress environment variables from the parent process which are no longer suitable for the child, and to provide additional variables to the child.
- You can start a “login shell” for the child, e.g. using `bash -l`. This will populate the enviroment as for a child. For many shells (including bash), prepending a hyphen to the name of the binary, i.e. passing `-bash` as `argv[0]`, has the same effect. A primary effect of this distinction is that a login shell will execute the `/etc/profile` and/or other profile shell scripts, which in turn set a large number of environment variables.
- For services which use PAM for authentication and session initialization, the `pam_env` module will take care of properly initializing the environment. You can have a look at that and its configuration, either to use it or to mimic its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Each process has a set of environment variables (that can be set in a shell by `export SOMEVAR=value` and so). They are inherited as-is by child processes. If you want to reset them, use `extern char **environ;` to get at the passed environment (see `environ(7)`), and then use `execle(3)` or `execve(3)` passing a new environment array with copied variable values. Some guidance on what and how do do it is given by David Wheeler in his ["Secure Unix/Linux programming HOWTO"](http://www.dwheeler.com/secure-programs/)

Comment: When the parent process is running as root,the environ is set to root environment. then when the parent process forks, the child process has the same environ (as was used by root) even though the effective uid/gid are changed for the child process. So my Question is how to access the environ of child process running as different uid/gid ?