# bash: FOO_VARIABLE=foo;./test does not pass foo variable to test - why not inherited?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I did web search and have read several articles on using variables in bash, including [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) but could not understand why running in bash `FOO_VARIABLE=foo;./test` does not result in test having `$FOO_VARIABLE` being `foo`:

> By default, when a process is created, it inherits a duplicate
>   environment of its parent process, except for explicit changes made by
>   the parent when it creates the child.

Also have read that: [Exception of inheritance of environment variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17758/exception-of-inheritance-of-environment-variables)

"except for explicit changes": `FOO_VARIABLE=foo ./test` - results in `test` script knowing `FOO_VARIABLE`, but why in first way it does not?

```
echo $0
-bash

cat ./test
echo $MY_TEST
MY_TEST=test$MY_TEST
echo $MY_TEST

MY_TEST=ret;./test

test
```

Tested on CentOS 7 and Mac OS.

ADDED:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772036/pass-all-variables-from-one-shell-script-to-another
second way is to source (2nd script is called from 1st), then no `export` needed - why my case is different?

AMEND to above: it was my rush and not very attentiveness to details: I missed `.` (dot) in sourcing section, now I've read: https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-vs-sourcing-it and that part is all clear.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/26318/environment-variable-vs-shell-variable-whats-the-difference
Yes, mine is local, but why is it not passed via inheritance (fork call)?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure why you state that your case is different. Which answer are you referring to? Your case seems equivalent. 2. It will be inherited in fact. But only by a **subshell**, not by arbitrary process. I.e. you can see it best here: `TEST=ret; (echo "shell variable=$TEST"; env|grep TEST)`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, so when script is run from other script it creates subshell, but when in interactive shell I run script - that script is NOT run in subshell? why is that?

Comment: No, a subshell has its own _settings_ (e.g. shell options and working directory) but technically runs in the same process. So there's no `fork()` involved. If there's a `fork()` command line arguments _and_ environment variables would be the way to make the other script see the variable. For example if you used `source ./test` to bring all the statements from `./test` into your current shell, the variable would _also_ be visible, because you don't actually start another process (assuming `./test` is written in the same shell dialect as the running shell).

Comment: @0xC0000022L, thank you! would be good (IMHO) if you include that valuable comment in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because at this point it's not an environment variable, it's a shell/local variable. You need to `export MY_TEST` it for this to work. An alternative would be this:

```
env MY_TEST=ret ./test
```

(In Bash also simply `MY_TEST=ret ./test`, but *with* `env` is more portable across shells.)

You could, by the way, verify this also by replacing your `./test` with `env|grep MY_TEST`.

In Bash (but not all other shells) you can also say

Executing it on the shell prompt will - in this case - be equivalent to what you'd be doing in a script.

Use:

```
export MY_TEST=ret; env|grep MY_TEST
```

to verify what I wrote.

Assuming `./test` were a shell script (of the same shell dialect) you could also use

```
source ./test
```

... to bring all the statements from `./test` into your current shell. The the shell/local variable would also be visible, because you don't actually start another process.

A subshell has its own settings (e.g. shell options and working directory) but technically runs in the same process. So there's no `fork()` involved. If there's a `fork()` command line arguments and *environment variables* would be the way to pass stuff to the other script/executable.

---

It's different from the case where a subshell inherits the parent shell's shell/local variables:

```
TEST=ret; (echo "shell variable=$TEST"; env|grep TEST)
```

Here the subshell (inside `(...)`) *will* see the variable, but it's still not an environment variable.

Comment: thanks a lot! part of my confusion was due to me missing `.` before script name in section about sourcing - I added AMEND section.

Answer (score 2):

In the first command,

```
FOO_VARIABLE=foo;./test
```

you assign the shell variable `FOO_VARIABLE` a value. Then you call `./test`.  Since `FOO_VARIABLE` is not exported, it is not an environment variable and it will therefore not be inherited by any script or program that you run.  This is why `./test` does not know about the variable.

In short: You set the shell variable "here" but it will not be available "there" (in `./test`).

In the other command,

```
FOO_VARIABLE=foo ./test
```

you set the value of `FOO_VARIABLE` in the environment of `./test` (i.e. you create an environment variable fro `./test` called `FOO_VARIABLE`).  The variable is not set in the current environment as an environment variable nor as a shell variable, only for the process resulting from running `./test`.

In short: You set the environment variable "there" (in `./test`) but not "here".

If you have an existing variable `FOO_VARIABLE` that you want a script or program to inherit as a environment variable, you will have to `export` it, i.e. make an environment variable from it:

```sh
FOO_VARIABLE=foo
export FOO_VARIABLE
./test
```

or, shorter

```sh
export FOO_VARIABLE=foo
./test
```

This sets the variable locally as well as makes it available in any created process (in `./test` for example).

Comment: thank you, please see my ADDED SECTION.

Comment: @AlexeiMartianov "Local" variable (shell variable) are not inherited across `fork()`.  This is how they are different from environment variables (exported variables).